# Extracting specific text / attribute value using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Following line of code:

```
results=(soup.find_all(type="folder"))
print(results)
```

will give me following output:

```
<object name="aaa" type="folder"/>
<object name="bbb" type="folder"/>
<object name="ccc" type="folder"/>
<object name="ddd" type="folder"/>
```

I only want to print:

```
aaa bbb ccc ddd
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate the `ResultSet` to get each value of name attribute.

###### Example

```
h = '''
<object name="aaa" type="folder"/>
<object name="bbb" type="folder"/>
<object name="ccc" type="folder"/>
<object name="ddd" type="folder"/>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(h)
for r in soup.find_all(type="folder"):
    print(r.get('name'))

->
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
```

or use `list comprehension` to get a list:

```
results = [r.get('name') for r in soup.find_all(type="folder")]
print(results)

->
['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd']
```

Convert `list` into a single string:

```
' '.join([r.get('name') for r in soup.find_all(type="folder")])

-> aaa bbb ccc ddd
```